# Not getting error stack trace in logs when exception occurs in callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I have a program which looks like this:

```
import { F1TelemetryClient, constants } from "@racehub-io/f1-telemetry-client";
const { PACKETS } = constants;

async function processParticipantsPacket(packet: any): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Received participants packet');
    throw new Error('message');
}

const client = new F1TelemetryClient({ port: 20777 });
client.on(PACKETS.participants, processParticipantsPacket);
```

I build and start the UDP server:

```
npm run build
npm start
```

and I get the following output:

```
UDP Client listening on 0.0.0.0:20777
```

I then call the server with a participants packet from a custom python script. The server receives the packet, but then provides no stack trace for the subsequently thrown exception. Here's the output:

```
Received participants packet
UDP Client closed
```

I would expect a stack trace between `Received participants packet` and `UDP Client closed` . Why does it instead fail silently? What can I do to make it print the whole stack trace to stdout?

Comment: My guess is that `F1TelemetryClient` catches the error and closes, emitting the message `UDP Client closed `